# Hibernate function not working

Tags: windows-7, windows, shutdown, hibernate

Just yesterday, using Sysinternals autoruns, I cleared some unwanted start-up applications, such as Nero Burning ROM. After I re-booted yesterday night, my hibernate function is not working, but is locking up and switches on when I move my mouse.

I fixed my fingerprint reader by enabling some entries.

I also tried

> powercfg -h off
>   powercfg -h on

I did not disable any Windows entries. I am running Windows 7 Home Premium.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Try turning on all the services again.  This should re-enable whatever is not working, but will slow down your machine.  You can then turn off teh services/programs a few at a time and you will be able to identify which program shouldn't have been turned off.

Unfortunately, just leaving windows services alone can be problematic - there may be device driver services installed by manufacturers of your hardware which need to be running in order to maintain full functionality of your machine.

Regarding hybernation, it may be worth trying:

- Running a Disk Cleanup
- powercfg -h off
- restart
- defragmentation
- powercfg -h on
- restart

Seems a bit long-winded, but has worked for people in the past.

Hope this helps.

Comment: And if that doesn't help you can try, as a last resort, system restore (assuming you didn't disabled that too).

Comment: @Fazer87 Will the Autoruns settings get saved even though I can not switch of the computer but will do a force shutdown and restart?

Comment: ys, they should so

Comment: @Fazer87 My computer shuts down and my fingerprint reader works now, but the Hibernate option is still not working I have enabled all of the entries from Microsoft and Digitalpersona. What can I do now?